# How to select records from sqlite table to get two specific tables?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite table with some columns in that only two row cells that can contain the same values at the same time, for instance cells in columns ColA (ValA1) and ColC (ValC1)

| ID | ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **ValA1** | ValB1 | **ValC1** | ValD1 |
| 2 | ValA2 | ValB2 | ValC2 | ValD2 |
| 3 | **ValA1** | ValB3 | **ValC1** | ValD3 |
| 4 | ValA4 | ValB4 | ValC4 | ValD4 |
| 5 | **ValA1** | ValB5 | **ValC1** | ValD5 |
| 6 | **ValA1** | ValB6 | **ValC1** | ValD6 |
| 7 | ValA7 | ValB7 | ValC7 | ValD7 |

I need 'SELECT' queries that return two tables

1. With records without the same values in ColA (ValA1) and ColC (ValC1) at the same time (that would be repeated, except for the very first, with ID = 1 in this example) and without 'ID' column

| ID | ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **ValA1** | ValB1 | **ValC1** | ValD1 |
| 2 | ValA2 | ValB2 | ValC2 | ValD2 |
| 4 | ValA4 | ValB4 | ValC4 | ValD4 |
| 7 | ValA7 | ValB7 | ValC7 | ValD7 |

2. With records that contain the same values in ColA (ValA1) and ColC (ValC1) at the same time and without 'ID' column and without row with ID = 1 in this example because this row is in the first table

| ID | ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | **ValA1** | ValB3 | **ValC1** | ValD3 |
| 5 | **ValA1** | ValB5 | **ValC1** | ValD5 |
| 6 | **ValA1** | ValB6 | **ValC1** | ValD6 |

I tried using a 'SELECT' query for the first case

1. SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD FROM table t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ColA, ColC FROM table t2 WHERE t1.ColA = t2.ColA AND t1.ColC = t2.ColC GROUP BY ColA HAVING (count(ColA)=1 AND count(ColC)=1))

and got table without row with ID = 1

| ID | ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | ValA2 | ValB2 | ValC2 | ValD2 |
| 4 | ValA4 | ValB4 | ValC4 | ValD4 |
| 7 | ValA7 | ValB7 | ValC7 | ValD7 |

and 'SELECT' query for the second case

2. SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD FROM table t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ColA, ColC FROM table t2 WHERE t1.ColA = t2.ColA AND t1.ColC = t2.ColC GROUP BY ColA HAVING (count(ColA)>1 AND count(ColC)>1))

and got table with row with ID = 1

| ID | ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **ValA1** | ValB1 | **ValC1** | ValD1 |
| 3 | **ValA1** | ValB3 | **ValC1** | ValD3 |
| 5 | **ValA1** | ValB5 | **ValC1** | ValD5 |
| 6 | **ValA1** | ValB6 | **ValC1** | ValD6 |

Thank you for replies

Comment: Posts should address one problem at a time, not multiple ones, consider narrowing this post. Also make sure to specify why your solutions don't work for you (if that's the issue), or explicitly provide a question at the bottom of the post, to allow readers understand the purpose of the post.

Comment: I don't agree with you. My post is about one problem: there is one table, and similar two 'SELECT' queries need to be applied to that table to get the other two tables. 
Also, in the post I wrote about what I need: 'I need 'SELECT' queries that return two tables' with detailed explanations. However, I will consider your point of view in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use the `row_number` function. For the first scenario, *records without the same values in ColA (ValA1) and ColC (ValC1) at the same time, except for the very first, with ID = 1 in this example*:

```
with t as
(
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by ColA, ColC order by ID) rn
from tbl_name
) 
select ID, ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD
from t
where rn = 1
order by ID
```

For the second scenario, *records that contain the same values in ColA (ValA1) and ColC (ValC1) at the same time and without 'ID' column and without row with ID = 1*:

```
with t as
(
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by ColA, ColC order by ID) rn
from tbl_name
) 
select ID, ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD
from t
where rn > 1
order by ID
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/YqZIsNCD)